# Generate C# code for Oracle table

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, code-generation

I have this XML for a table structure in Oracle (export option in PL/SQL developer). How can I generate code in C# for get entity class?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ROWDATA>
  <ROW>
    <Name>ID_TRANSACCION</Name>
    <Type>NUMBER(12)</Type>
    <Nullable></Nullable>
    <Default></Default>
    <Comments>Identificador unico de la transacci&#243;n.</Comments>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <Name>ID_RECIBO</Name>
    <Type>NUMBER(12)</Type>
    <Nullable></Nullable>
    <Default></Default>
    <Comments>Identificador unico del recibo.</Comments>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <Name>IMPORTE_COBRAR</Name>
    <Type>NUMBER(10,2)</Type>
    <Nullable>Y</Nullable>
    <Default></Default>
    <Comments>Importe a cobrar</Comments>
  </ROW>
</ROWDATA>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Code to do what exactly?

Comment: Do you mean a POCO class of the Tables ?

Comment: the idea: Generate code C# using XML generated using PL/SQL.

thnaks

Comment: @Alhambra Eidos: Formatted your code so it is visible. In the future, please take more care how your questions look like before you post them.

Comment: @Alhambra: Feedback on my answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28VS.71%29.aspx) - this tool allows you to create an xsd schema from a sample xml document (your export form Oracle) and create a .net class from a given xsd schema.

Now that your sample code is visible it's clear that you would need to transform the xml before you could use it in connection with xsd.exe.

If you are looking for oracle support of the **.NET EntityFramework** you need to use a specific **Oracle provider**. One example would be [DataDirect](http://www.datadirect.com/products/net/entity-framework/index.ssp).

---

**sample xslt for schema generation**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="xsd:schema">
            <xsl:attribute name="attributeFormDefault">
                qualified
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="elementFormDefault">
                qualified
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ROWDATA">
        <xsl:element name="xsd:element">
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:element name="xsd:complexType">
                <xsl:element name="xsd:sequence">
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ROW">
        <xsl:element name="xsd:element">
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="./Name"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="nillable">
                <xsl:value-of select="contains(./Nullable, 'Y')"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:if test="./Default != ''">
                <xsl:attribute name="default">
                    <xsl:value-of select="./Default"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:element name="xsd:annotation">
                <xsl:element name="xsd:documentation">
                    <xsl:value-of select="./Comments"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="xsd:simpleType">
                <xsl:element name="xsd:restriction">
                    <xsl:attribute name="base">xsd:decimal</xsl:attribute>
                    <!-- elaborate data type here -->
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The resulting schema document can be used as an input for xsd.exe.